# How to make a function that bounces between two values on tick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a function that at first sets the value to 0 but after some time it sets the variable to a new value, however after some time it again sets the variable to 0 and it must bounce between those values indefinitly.

```
if (this.descriptionRef.current) {
        const { scrollHeight } = this.descriptionRef.current

        setTimeout(function run() {
          this.setState({ y: scrollHeight })
          console.log(scrollHeight)
          setTimeout(run, 7000)
        }, 7000)
      }
```

So I have this nested setTimeout function that must do the ticking part but I need to somehow change the setState value.

Comment: you could do a `setInterval` and a conditional `setState` inside it that sets new value based on previous value (0 to new value, new value to 0 and so on..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generator function

```
function* switchValues (value) {
  while(true){
    yield 0;
    yield value;
   }
}

const valueSwitcher = switchValues({ y: 10 })
console.log(valueSwitcher.next().value) //0
console.log(valueSwitcher.next().value) //the value you passed in, in this case an object
```

It will pick up the execution of the function where you last left it (after yield).

You could try to use this in your code like so:

```
if (this.descriptionRef.current) {
        const { scrollHeight } = this.descriptionRef.current

        setTimeout(function run() {
          this.setState(valueSwitcher.next().value)
          console.log(scrollHeight)
          setTimeout(run, 7000)
        }, 7000)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use setInterval?

```
let x = 0
setInterval(() => x = x === 0 ? "something else" : 0, 7000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (number === 10) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNumber(90)
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNumber(10)
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [number]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```